# What is the difference between "My school's homework tutor" "My school homework's tutor" and "My school homework tutor"?

Tags: possessives, parsing, attributive-nouns

Here is the situation:

- The students of each subject have to make sure they have done their homework and bring their homework back to school.
- The tutor of each subject will correct the homework for their students.

Given that context, what is the difference between these three:

> *My school's homework tutor*

vs

> *My school homework's tutor*

vs

> *My school homework tutor (without 's)*

*School* is an attributive, *school homework* is also an attributive.

I have read some of the similar questions on ELL, but I can not solve the above  question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The noun that you attach the possessive "'s" to is the owner of what comes afterward.

> My school's homework tutor

The homework tutor belongs to the school. This is a reasonable construction - there may be homework tutors for other schools and you are talking about the one from your school.

> My school homework's tutor

The tutor belongs to the school homework. This doesn't make sense - a tutor can't belong to homework.

> My school homework tutor

School and homework describe tutor. This describes the tutor that helps you with your school homework. You may have another tutor that helps you with your piano playing or something other than your school homework.

I would not include school in "My school homework tutor". I would just say "homework" because most people assume that homework comes from school. If it were a different type of homework, like "chess club homework" I would mention the type to be clear that it was different from what most people expect.

Comment: You could have a special tutor, privately hired, to assist you with your homework (you "school homework's tutor") perhaps. Not the situation the OP describes, but a possible one.

Comment: @FrancisDavey You still wouldn't use the possessive though - it would just be your "school homework tutor". The tutor "belongs" to you and is of the type that helps you with your homework.

Comment: +1. However the only thing I would add to your answer is that in the case of *my school-homework tutor*, I would hyphenate school-homework.  Not everyone will agree with this but it is the academic fashion in British universities.

Comment: @WS2 I just don't like "school homework"--it's only ever been "homework" for me. I've also never had one tutor, forget having to distinguish between the tutor for my school homework and the one for my other kind of homework :)

Answer (score 1):

In

> My school's homework tutor

it means that there is a person in the position of "homework tutor", that works for the school.

This seems closest to your intended meaning.

But in

> my school homework's tutor

it seems like the school homework itself has a tutor, which is not the case.